# Зайти на флешку в linux

Tags: linux

Все привет. Нужно зайти на флешку в терминале путь:/dev/ttyUSB0
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Судя по названию - это usb-модем, либо какой-нибудь преобразователь usb-com. но никак не "флешка"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/dev/ttyUSB0 - это как бы более низкий уровень доступа к флешке. Устройство для флешки скорее всего будет выглядеть немного по другому. Самый простой способ найти - это вставить флешку и сразу в терминале запустит команду dmesg. Там в конце должно быть что то вида

```
new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
```

это значит, что как минимум само устройство было распознано на низком уровне.

Чуть ниже будет где то такое

```
New USB device found, idVendor=1111, idProduct=1234, bcdDevice= 1.00
```

и смотрим ещё ниже по тексту и там должно быть такое

```
[sde] 121438208 512-byte logical blocks: (62.2 GB/57.9 GiB)
```

это значит, что флешка (диск) найдены, размер виден и известно имя - sde (у Вас, естественно, может быть другое). Но только sde - это название всей флешки, а конкретный раздел на флешке будет называться sde1 (или другие числа в конце, в зависимости от разбивки диска).

Проверяем наличие (флешка вставлена)

```
ls /dev/sde*
```

(вместо буквы e Вам нужно будет подставить свою. Если линукс совсем-совсем древний, то там будет /dev/hda* или подобное).

Ок, теперь имя уже известно. Можно пробовать монтировать. Для начала нужно создать для него каталог, можно даже в домашнем каталоге. Пусть это будет /home/Alexandr/usbstick Теперь монтируем

```
mkdir /home/Alexandr/usbstick
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sde1 /home/Alexandr/usbstick
```

тут есть важный параметр - `-t vfat` - большинство флешек в fat, но бывают и в ntfs. (тогда нужно `-t ntfs-3g`)

В целом, очень странно, что флешка не подмонтировалась сама. Скорее всего она либо сломана, либо она на ntfs, а в системе не установлено под нее поддержка. Последние 10-20 строк с dmesg в момент вставки флешки могут прояснить ситуацию.

Comment: добавлю, что если это модем, то он также может содержать виртуальный cd-rom и соответственно определяться как `/dev/srX`.

Comment: 1. Разве mount сам не определяет файловую систему? Вроде я образы не указывая её монтировал. 2. Для флешек популярность набирает exFat - думаю, с его поддержкой больше вопросов, чем с ntfs.

Answer (score 1):

А флешка точно /dev/ttyUSB0? обычно они в системе /dev/sdxN. Спросите, какие накопители есть в системе с помощью `fdisk -l` (для выполнения нужны права root). Там по объему вычислите свою флешку, либо выньте её, посмотрите какой записи не стало и вставьте обратно). Последний шаг, например флешка sdb1 - `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/flash`, для выполнения mount нужны права root, поэтому sudo, либо из-под root. Если папки /mnt/flash нет, создайте её, либо смонтируйте в любую другую. Если монтирование прошло успешно, то на флешку вы зайдете `cd /mnt/flash`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй:

```
cd /media/root
ls
```

После в консоли появится название флешки, ну а дальше

```
cd [Название_Флешки]
```